# How do a i+=2 for-loop with equal in Swift?

Tags: swift, loops

How to write this loop in Swift?

```
for(int i=0; i<=100; i+=2){
   //
}
```

I need exactly <=100, not <100.

The following code works like <100:

```
for index in stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 2){
    //
}
```

So do we have any chance to have <= in swift?
Many thanks!

Comment: how about using `to: 102` in swift?

Comment: This how I did. But was curious how to do it properly. Im new in swift

Comment: @Maurice Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

There is an API.

Replace [`to`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride)

> Returns a sequence from a starting value to, but not including, an end value, stepping by the specified amount.

with [`through`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride)

> Returns a sequence from a starting value toward, and possibly including, an end value, stepping by the specified amount.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in stride(from: 0, through: 100, by: 2) { }
```

Comment: @Magnas I assume because it's terse and code only, rather than nicely explanatory like vadian's answer.